# parsing repeating child elements python

Tags: python, xml, repeat

I am trying to parse an XML document that contains repeating child elements using Python.  When I attempt to parse the data, it creates an empty file.  If I comment out the repeating child elements code (see bolded section in python script below), the document generates correctly.   Can someone help?

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<FRPerformance xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <FRPerformanceShareClassCurrency>
    <FundCode>00190</FundCode>
    <CurrencyID>USD</CurrencyID>
    <FundShareClassCode>A</FundShareClassCode>
    <ReportPeriodFrequency>Quarterly</ReportPeriodFrequency>
    <ReportPeriodEndDate>06/30/2012</ReportPeriodEndDate>
    <Net>
      <Annualized>
        <Year1>-4.909000000</Year1>
        <Year3>10.140000000</Year3>
        <Year5>-22.250000000</Year5>
        <Year10>-7.570000000</Year10>
        <Year15>-4.730000000</Year15>
        <Year20>-0.900000000</Year20>
        <SI>1.900000000</SI>
      </Annualized>
    </Net>
    <Gross>
      <Annualized>
        <Month3>1.279000000</Month3>
        <YTD>7.294000000</YTD>
        <Year1>-0.167000000</Year1>
        <Year3>11.940000000</Year3>
        <Year5>-21.490000000</Year5>
        <Year10>-7.120000000</Year10>
        <Year15>-4.420000000</Year15>
        <Year20>-0.660000000</Year20>
        <SI>2.110000000</SI>
      </Annualized>
      <Cumulative>
        <Month1Back>2.288000000</Month1Back>
        <Month2Back>-1.587000000</Month2Back>
        <Month3Back>0.610000000</Month3Back>
        <CurrentYear>7.294000000</CurrentYear>
        <Year1Back>-2.409000000</Year1Back>
        <Year2Back>13.804000000</Year2Back>
        <Year3Back>20.287000000</Year3Back>
        <Year4Back>-78.528000000</Year4Back>
        <Year5Back>-0.101000000</Year5Back>
        <Year6Back>9.193000000</Year6Back>
        <Year7Back>2.659000000</Year7Back>
        <Year8Back>9.208000000</Year8Back>
        <Year9Back>25.916000000</Year9Back>
        <Year10Back>-3.612000000</Year10Back>
      </Cumulative>
      <HistoricReturns>
        <HistoricReturns_Item>
          <Date>Fri, 28 Feb 1997 00:00:00 -0600</Date>
          <Return>32058.090000000</Return>
        </HistoricReturns_Item>
        <HistoricReturns_Item>
          <Date>Fri, 28 Feb 2003 00:00:00 -0600</Date>
          <Return>36415.110000000</Return>
        </HistoricReturns_Item>
        <HistoricReturns_Item>
          <Date>Fri, 29 Feb 2008 00:00:00 -0600</Date>
          <Return>49529.290000000</Return>
        </HistoricReturns_Item>
        <HistoricReturns_Item>
          <Date>Fri, 30 Apr 1993 00:00:00 -0600</Date>
          <Return>21621.500000000</Return>
        </HistoricReturns_Item>
</<HistoricReturns>
```

**Python script**

```
## Create command line arguments for XML file and tageName
xmlFile = sys.argv[1]
tagName = sys.argv[2]


tree = ET.parse(xmlFile)
root = tree.getroot()

## Setup the file for output
saveout = sys.stdout
output_file =  open('parsedXML.csv', 'w')
sys.stdout = output_file

## Parse XML

for node in root.findall(tagName):
    fundCode = node.find('FundCode').text
    curr = node.find('CurrencyID').text
    shareClass = node.find('FundShareClassCode').text
    for node2 in node.findall('./Net/Annualized'):
        year1 = node2.findtext('Year1')
        year3 = node2.findtext('Year3')
        year5 = node2.findtext('Year5')
        year10 = node2.findtext('Year10')
        year15 = node2.findtext('Year15')
        year20 = node2.findtext('Year20')
        SI = node2.findtext('SI')
        for node3 in node.findall('./Gross'):
            for node4 in node3.findall('./Annualized'):
                month3 = node4.findtext('Month3')
                ytd = node4.findtext('YTD')
                year1g = node4.findtext('Year1')
                year3g = node4.findtext('Year3')
                year5g = node4.findtext('Year5')
                year10g = node4.findtext('Year10')
                year15g = node4.findtext('Year15')
                year20g = node4.findtext('Year2')
                SIg = node4.findtext('SI')
            for node5 in node3.findall('./Cumulative'):
                month1b = node5.findtext('Month1Back')
                month2b = node5.findtext('Month2Back')
                month3b = node5.findtext('Month3Back')
                curYear = node5.findtext('CurrentYear')
                year1b = node5.findtext('Year1Back')
                year2b = node5.findtext('Year2Back')
                year3b = node5.findtext('Year3Back')
                year4b = node5.findtext('Year4Back')
                year5b = node5.findtext('Year5Back')
                year6b = node5.findtext('Year6Back')
                year7b = node5.findtext('Year7Back')
                year8b = node5.findtext('Year8Back')
                year9b = node5.findtext('Year9Back')
                year10b = node5.findtext('Year10Back')
        **for node6 in node.findall('./HistoricReturns'):
            for node7 in node6.findall('./HistoricReturns_Item'):
                hDate = node7.findall('Date')
                hReturn = node7.findall('Return')**
                print(fundCode, curr, shareClass,year1, year3, year5, year10, year15, year15, year20, SI,month3, ytd, year1g, year3g, year5g, year10g, year15g, year20g, SIg, month1b, month2b, month3b, curYear, year1b, year2b, year3b, year4b, year5b, year6b, year7b, year8b,year9b,year10b, hDate, hReturn)
```

Comment: This is the child element (HistoricReturns/HistoricReturns_Item) and this is the code in question.   **for node6 in node.findall('./HistoricReturns'):
            for node7 in node6.findall('./HistoricReturns_Item'):
                hDate = node7.findall('Date')
                hReturn = node7.findall('Return')**

Comment: Do not use comments to clarify the question. Edit the question instead.

Comment: The XML is still not well-formed after the edit. And there are import statements missing in the Python code.

Answer (score 1):

The sample XML and the python code don't match up in terms of structure. Either

- you're missing a closing `</Gross>` tag from the XML (which should be before the `<HistoricReturns>` section starts) - in which case the code is correct or
- the code should be `for node6 in node3.findall('./HistoricReturns'):` i.e. `node3` instead of `node`

N.B. The XML sample isn't complete (it isn't well-formed XML) because it's missing closing tags for `Gross`, `FRPerformanceShareClassCurrency` and `FRPerformance` so this makes it impossible to answer the question definitively. Hope this helps though.

Comment: Sorry about the XML. One of the elements collapsed.  I’ve updated the XML above.

Comment: Did you see the comment from @mzjn? After your update, the XML still isn't well formed. It's because not every starting tag has a corresponding closing tag.

I'd suggest running your example code against your example document and you should see this. It will also prompt you to add the missing imports to the python code. This will make it much easier to help you.